# Create dynamic GameObjects and transform their positions together from JSON data

Tags: unity-game-engine, position

Consider this dataset:

```c#
[
   {
     PartId: 0,
     Positions: [
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, timeCode: 0.0000 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, timeCode: 0.0025 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 2, timeCode: 0.0050 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 3, timeCode: 0.0075 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 4, timeCode: 0.0100 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 5, timeCode: 0.0125 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 6, timeCode: 0.0150 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 7, timeCode: 0.0175 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 8, timeCode: 0.0200 },
     ]
   },
   {
     PartId: 1,
     Positions: [
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, timeCode: 0.0000 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 2, timeCode: 0.0025 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 4, timeCode: 0.0050 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 6, timeCode: 0.0075 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 8, timeCode: 0.0100 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 10, timeCode: 0.0125 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 12, timeCode: 0.0150 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 14, timeCode: 0.0175 },
       { x: 0, y: 0, z: 16, timeCode: 0.0200 },
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I am able to load and parse the JSON data and I can create a new GameObject for each PartId. I am trying to figure out the best way to transform each "Part" according to the Position collection all at the same time.

I have an empty GameObject in the scene with an attached class. Inside the Start method I get the JSON data and then in a loop I create the GameObject class, set its initial position and then start a coroutine defined in the same class.

Main class:

```c#
void Start() {
    // do json stuff...
    // ........
    // then
    // for each part...

    foreach(PartGroup pg in Parts) {
        // create a new GameObject from the Part class
        Part part = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Part)) as Part;
        // send this part data to the new GameObject
        part.PartGroup = pg;
        // set the initial position for the part
        part.Init();

        // start a IEnumerator Coroutine in the part class
        StartCoroutine(part.PlayFrom());
    }
}
```

Part class:

```c#
public void Init() {
    Joint = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    Joint.transform.localScale = new Vector3(jointSize, jointSize, jointSize);
    Joint.transform.position = new Vector3(PartGroup.Positions[0].X, PartGroup.Positions[0].Z, PartGroup.Positions[0].Y);
}
public IEnumerator PlayFrom(float time = 0f) {
    while (PlayBack(time)) {
        yield return null;

        time += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
bool PlayBack(float time) {
    float sample = time / (Time.fixedDeltaTime / speed);
    int previousIndex = (int)(sample);
    int last = PartGroup.Positions.Count - 1;

    if (previousIndex < last) {
        int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
        float interpolation = sample - previousIndex;

        Joint.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(
            new Vector3(PartGroup.Positions[previousIndex].X, PartGroup.Positions[previousIndex].Z, PartGroup.Positions[previousIndex].Y),
            new Vector3(PartGroup.Positions[nextIndex].X, PartGroup.Positions[nextIndex].Z, PartGroup.Positions[nextIndex].Y),
            interpolation);

        return true;
    }
    Joint.transform.position = new Vector3(PartGroup.Positions[last].X, PartGroup.Positions[last].Z, PartGroup.Positions[last].Y);

    return false;
}
```

This is how I currently have it set up. It does work, but it is not smooth motion and sometimes it seems to lag or jump frames. Is this the best way to accomplish this, or is there a better way (like FixedUpdate)? I have set the fixed time property in my project settings to match the data timeCode.

Any help with best practices for stuff like this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) in

```c#
time += Time.deltaTime;
```

and

```c#
float sample = time / (Time.deltaTime / speed);
```

[Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are executed together with all `Update` calls so using [`fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) breaks the frame independency.

or probably use [`WaitForFixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html) to execute it like `FixedUpdate`

```c#
while (PlayBack(time)) {
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    time += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}
```

---

Also in

```c#
foreach(PartGroup pg in Parts) 
{
    // create a new GameObject from the Part class
    Part part = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Part)) as Part;
    // send this part data to the new GameObject
    part.PartGroup = pg;
    // set the initial position for the part
    part.Init();

    // start a IEnumerator Coroutine in the part class
    StartCoroutine(part.PlayFrom());
}
```

it looks like you are adding a component for each element in the list all to one and the same `GameObject` .. I don't know if that's what you planned to do. [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) does not create a new `GameObject` with that component but attaches that component to the same `gameObject` that script is attached to.

You probably ment to use [`new GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html)

```c#
Part part = new GameObject("new GameObject").AddComponent<Part>();
// make it a child of this gameObject?
part.SetParent(gameObject, false);
```

also the calculations

```c#
float sample = time / (Time.fixedDeltaTime / speed);
int previousIndex = (int)(sample);

...

float interpolation = sample - previousIndex;
```

seems a bit odd .. are you sure it always returns a value between `0` and `1`?

Comment: Hmm, changing it to deltaTime makes the animation much worse. Seems to jump around to previous positions in the collection

Comment: Thank you for the help. I see what you mean by the GameObject and class. I changed it as you suggested but now there is no Sphere for each part/class. How would I attach a Sphere to it for each part?

Comment: Re: the calculations...honestly I got this code from another example I found that was somewhat related to this. I'm not sure if it's correct or proper for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: shouldn't this be done calling `Init()`? `public void Init() {
    Joint = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    Joint.transform.localScale = new Vector3(jointSize, jointSize, jointSize);
    Joint.transform.position = new Vector3(PartGroup.Positions[0].X, PartGroup.Positions[0].Z, PartGroup.Positions[0].Y);
}` but you probably also have to make it a child of the object? I don't exactly know what is supposed to happen there

Comment: Ok, I change my foreach to this...

foreach(PartGroup pg in Parts) {
    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    Joint joint = sphere.AddComponent<Joint>();
    joint.BodyPositions = pg;
    joint.Init();

    StartCoroutine(joint.PlayFrom());
} and removed it from inside the Part class.

Comment: Is there anyway to run this off of fixedUpdate since the position data is all the same and consistent? I feel like it would run smoother? I changed all fixedDeltaTime to deltaTime and again, it's very jumpy and not any better (worse actually). I appreciate your help!

Comment: As said you can try using `WaitForFixedUpdate` to make the Coroutine execute like `FixedUpdate`